# How to mathematically model noise?

Tags: signal-processing, noise

In my project I have to perform analysis of noise effect in certain signal. I am just wondering how is noise formally described? Up to now I always simulate a noisy signal using MATLAB in an additive way. For example suppose the clean signal is a sine signal then I would just add random numbers distributed equally between a pair of values to this signal. I am not sure if this is the correct way as I can freely choose any values for the upper and lower bounds for the noise as I want. Also, I would also appreciate if someone can suggest me books which covers noise analysis, like noise in Fourier transform and differentiating noisy functions.

Comment: I prefer to use 'wgn' command in MATLAB for white noise. The introduction to probability and stochastic processes by Gubner covers noise and its connection to spectrum via Fourier transforms.

Comment: Thanks @minion, I will try the book you recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use gaussian noise, the you only have specify the variance. So you could set this proportional to the "amount of disturbance" you want. (choose the mean zero). To obtain $N$ independent noise samples you could use the command normrnd in Matlab.

Comment: That's it, why are there different types of noise like white noise, pink noise, Gaussian noise etc? In which case each of them is relevant when used to describe certain physical processes? By the way, about the additive noise I have always implemented, is that justifiable? Let's say the signal is f(x) and the noise, whatever type it is, is N, then the noisy signal is just f(x)+N?

Comment: Additive noise models are the easiest to analyze and work well in many engineering applications.

Comment: You should definitely start by analyzing additive noise mdoels. But there are others, for sure.

Comment: Ok, that's quite an insight for an introduction level. Also, if I were to perform math analysis on a noisy signal, it seems that I can only do this if I work with the discretized version of the function f(x), sampled to a finite number of values. Because I don't see a way to model the noise N as a continuous function.